# Getting more accurate area size using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area, measurements

I'm using Natural Earth's shapefiles and try to match them to the real area size. I'm utilizing $area expression, but no matter what ellipsoid measurement I use the result seems to be very off. For example, most ellipsoids give Norrbotten county size of 104 725 km², while it should be 98 244 km². I don't need it to be absolutely precise, but I feel like over 5 000 km² offset is too much.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using QGIS

CRS: Sphere_Robinson (EPSG: 53030)

Comment: Well, for beginners, you don't tell us, which software you're working with. Then you don't tell us, which CRS you're working with, as well as the parameters of area calculations.

Comment: @Erik The expression $area has no parameters

Comment: Please add an EPSG-code of your CRS. Also, under Project -> properties -> general you can tell QGIS which ellipsoid to use for area and distance calculations - aka parameters.

Comment: @Erik I tried using different ellipsoid measures and they resulted in inaccuracies.

Comment: Wait, you're using a worldwide m-based CRS to measure areas close to the polar circle and are wondering you get inaccurate results? I strongly suggest you use a local CRS for this kind of calculations, e.g. SWEREF99 TM ([EPSG 3006](https://epsg.io/3006)).

Comment: Norbotten county has an area of 98 244 km² (as you write) according to the english Wikipedia. Or 98 911 km² according to the swedish Wikipedia. Or 105.208,8 km² according to the german Wikipedia. So which one is the "correct" one?

Comment: I think there is a more fundamental problem involved: we are all used to see area number for administrative units. But we seldom get any information how this area was measured. Planar, ellipsoid? In what CRS? And don't forget: geoid and topography (mountains, valleys) significantly change the results. So the "areas" we are used to are in many cases not more than very rough approximations of the actual surface of the earth.

Comment: Also consider the "Coastline paradox": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox - as well as the coastline, the area could be considered not a "flat" (2 dimensional), but a "fractal" surface. Depending of how detailed you measure, you will get more and more details and the area will increase endlessly. Of course, that's not what we think of when comparing the area of administrative units, but gives an idea of how meaningless area measurements are without stating how and what was calculated.

Comment: @babel Insightful, I didn't realize the disparity between area sizes. That being said, I don't really see the point of playing with region-specific CRS because the differences in area sizes seem marginal. For example, with the aforementioned SWEREF99, Norbotten is 104 864 km², the difference being 139 km² to Sphere_Robinson.

Comment: What I wanted to stress is not that regional specific CRS are not relevant, to the contrary. Most "reliable" measurements will be probably done exactely with regional specific CRS. So as long as you use the same method of measurement, the results should be comparable (although the generalized borders of the natural earth polygon accounts for a minor discrepancy) - an area almost 6.6% larger than the value you have from somewhere indicates that you undertake some other method of measurement. So you should always check (if possible) how the values you get from somewhere were measured.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wikipedia and almost all other information sources give only the number of square kilometers, without any further information who calculated this number on the basis of what and how they did it. Best go to the official geoportal of the country in question (Sweden in your case) and look for some official data, like polygon shapes of administrative units. They often already cotain area measurements as attributes. There should be a documentation (metadata) that should inform about the kind of measurement.

Comment: See this paper about landscape surface about why and in which context this is more accurate to work with: Jeff S. Jenness: Calculating landscape surface area from digital elevation models, in: Wildlife Society Bulletin 2004, 32(3), 829-839, online: https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_other/rmrs_2004_jenness_j001.pdf

Comment: An example of such metadata for the swiss communes: https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/products/landscape/boundaries3D
If you download the data, there are metadata files. In the german version, on p. 11 you find the information Attribut SHAPE_AREA; Data Type: Double; Description [my translation from german]: planimetric area of the polygon
On p. 5, titel 1.8: Reference system comes in two versions: LV03 LN02 and LV95 LN02, with additional information about these on its website: https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/wissen-fakten/geodaesie-vermessung/bezugsrahmen/lokal.html

Comment: If you have such information, you know how measurement was done and than, you can start your own measurment and compare. Otherwise, it's a guess in the dark

Comment: So, to make it short: you almost always will get "projected" area values, not "real-world" areas. If you would want to know how many sheet of paper you need to cover the whole of Norbotten country, you shold stick to something like the paper linked above. Projected area values do not take into consideration topography. So the difference to the real surface area is bigger in mountainous countries (as Switzerland or Austria) compared to flatter ones (as the Netherlands or the Estonia).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116850/discussion-on-question-by-chlodio-getting-more-accurate-area-size-using-qgis).