# Area given by software (QGIS and MapWindowGIS) DIFFERS from value given by revenue official

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area, mapwindow

Revenue official has given area as 10.12 acres. I used QGIS and MapWindowGIS with projection UTM Zone 45 to measure area. The software gave area value of 13.06 acres.

Why the difference?

Comment: Where is your area located, it might be that UTM Zone 45 is not correct for your case. See; https://epsg.io/32645

Answer (score 1):

You should find out in what CRS the area of 10.12 acres was measured and than use the same CRS - otherwise a comparison does not make much sense as exact values will differ due to differing characteristics of the CRS. If it's official data, it was probably measured in a local CRS valid for the country/state involved, not in UTM.

You should also know some further details: were measurements made planar or elloipsoidal? Do you have exactely the same polygons as were used for the official measurements?

If all these paramenters are unknown, it is no surprise that measurements differ, to the contrary: it would be a surprise if they matched.

---

To add some background information, I cite comments I made to [another post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/380558/88814). As this information is quite hidden there, I guess it does not harm to have it here. To sum it up: all kind of measurements in fact are models of the reality. As long as you don't know how data modelling was made, you can't compare.

I think there is a more fundamental problem involved: we are all used to see area number for administrative units. But we seldom get any information how this area was measured. Planar, ellipsoid? In what CRS? And don't forget: geoid and topography (mountains, valleys) significantly change the results. So the "areas" we are used to are in many cases not more than very rough approximations of the actual surface of the earth.

Also consider the "[Coastline paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox)": as well as the coastline, the area could be considered not a "flat" (2 dimensional), but a "fractal" surface. Depending of how detailed you measure, you will get more and more details and the area will increase endlessly. Of course, that's not what we think of when comparing the area of administrative units, but gives an idea of how meaningless area measurements are without stating how and what was calculated.

Unfortunately, Wikipedia and almost all other information sources give only the number of square kilometers, without any further information who calculated this number on the basis of what and how they did it. The official geoportal of the country in question often already cotains area measurements as attributes (as seems to be the case here). There should be a documentation (metadata) that informs about what kind of measurement was used to calculate these numbers.

See this paper about landscape surface about why and in which context this is more accurate to work with: Jeff S. Jenness: [Calculating landscape surface area from digital elevation models](https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_other/rmrs_2004_jenness_j001.pdf), in: Wildlife Society Bulletin 2004, 32(3), 829-839.

An example of such [metadata for the swiss communes](http://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/products/landscape/boundaries3D): If you download the data, there are metadata files. In the german version, on p. 11 you find the information Attribut SHAPE_AREA; Data Type: Double; Description [my translation from german]: planimetric area of the polygon. On p. 5, titel 1.8: Reference system comes in two versions: LV03 LN02 and LV95 LN02, with [additional information about these on its website](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/wissen-fakten/geodaesie-vermessung/bezugsrahmen/lokal.html).

If you have such information, you know how measurement was done and than, you can start your own measurment and compare. Otherwise, it's a guess in the dark.

So, to make it short: you almost always will get "projected" area values, not "real-world" areas. If you would want to know how many sheet of paper you need to actually cover the whole of a certain area, you shold stick to something like the paper linked above. Projected area values do not take into consideration topography. So the difference to the real surface area is bigger in mountainous countries (as Switzerland or Austria) compared to flatter ones (as the Netherlands or the Estonia).

Comment: The landscape surface paper by Jenness that you cite looks interesting.  However, that url leads to a dead link, but I was able to download it at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232669735_Calculating_Landscape_Surface_Area_from_Digital_Elevation_Models/link/5aa9358b0f7e9b88266e8a06/download

Comment: OK, updated the link. Normally, areas are calculated in planar or ellipsoidal mode - the paper by Janness is a more accurate, however rather exotic mode of calculating surfaces.